# How to use SQLyogTunnel_ciom.php

Tags: php, mysql, sqlyog

I am working with mysql credentials where I always get an error : access denied for root@user

I have ssh details so I used heidisql and sqlyog to connect to database, It worked. 
Now I have to write code for this database using php.

mysqli_connect gives the same error.
I searched and tried many things (like using ssh -fNg -L) but non of them worked for me then some how I got a file  'SQLyogTunnel_ciom.php'

but I have no idea how to use it. I tried to include it and call its function but that is not working either.
Kindly suggest me how to work around in this situation.

Comment: The SQLyogTunnel.php is designed to work only with SQLyog but not with other applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.webyog.com/2012/10/31/think-beyond-phpmyadmin-to-access-mysql-on-a-shared-host/

This blog post explains how you can create something like SQLyogTunnel.php to access database in a shared hosting.